# Ruby on Rails and LDAP (Active Directory)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-directory

I am trying to connect to an active directory, I already made the connection, I need to be able to upload a file to the active directory, how can I do it, having access already?

```
ldap.open do |ldap|
 p 'Here and where do I have to do the manipulation of the file?'
end
```

The login of the app, is with devise, and I need to create a function where a different user and a different password login in the active directory and can upload files there

**UPDATE**

The requirement is the following: I have an app in rails with authentication with gem DEVISE, it has a module that allows uploading files to a fodler in the server, these folders are in an active directory, I have a special credentials to access that folder (Active Directory), as I do for access to the directory active with credencial that I have, which are different from the login of the user in the app?

Comment: *..upload a file to the active directory..* - Never heard anyone has tried it; IMO probably this feature is also not available! Can you describe what type of file you want to upload, and why?

Comment: any update to your situation? i have similar situation (i need to save files to external file server). i am interested.. is the "file upload" really needed to be handled by "ldap", or can other gem do it? ex, carrierwave gem. and in this carrierwave gem possibly it has config for setting where the files will be uploaded. maybe this gem can help us? (https://github.com/luan/carrierwave-ftp)..